# Every 9th row becomes checked

Tags: android, list, checkbox, backup, row

iam working on a application backup app and i want to make so it only backup those apps that i selected via a checkbox. I have implemented the checkbox to the list but when i check a row every 9th row before and after it also becomes checked :S

PS. i also appreciate if some one could help me on the whay an sole how i can make so the app-backup also work :)

(this is just a pice of the complete java file)

```
private static class AppViewHolder {
    TextView top_view;
    TextView bottom_view;
    ImageView icon;
    CheckBox check_mark;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
}

private class TableView extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {

    private TableView() {
        super(main.this, R.layout.tablerow_02, mAppList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        AppViewHolder holder;
        ApplicationInfo info = mAppList.get(position);

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow_02, parent, false);

            holder = new AppViewHolder();
            holder.top_view = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_view);
            holder.bottom_view = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_view);

            holder.check_mark = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


            holder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
            holder.icon.setMaxHeight(40);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (AppViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.check_mark.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if ( isChecked )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "#" + position + " is checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "#" + position + " is unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        holder.top_view.setText(info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
        holder.bottom_view.setText(info.packageName);

        //this should not throw the exception
        try {
            holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mPackMag.getApplicationIcon(info.packageName));
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because you aren't recycling views properly. You should keep a array of booleans, one for each item in the list. Then in `getView` you need to call `setChecked` on `holder.check_mark` based upon the value in that list of booleans.